# C# Windows Forms glitch while creating a control

Tags: c#, windows, forms, controls

I somehow noticed, that while I'm creating a control in my application, it first appears as weird rectangle and then it "shrinks" to it's correct form.

[First thing you'll see after creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqheB.png)

[Correctly created object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54o54.png)

My question is, why I first see the rectangle in top left corner and then it suddenly changes to it's correct form. It's like split second thing (I had to use Thread.Sleep 'cos it's impossible to screenshot it), but my eyes can still see this and I'm really triggered when it's happening.

This is the code, where I'm creating the control:

```
var label = new Label
{
    AutoSize = true,
    TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft,
    Font = new Font("Courier New", 9F, FontStyle.Regular,
        GraphicsUnit.Point, 238),
    Text = keyword,
    Margin = new Padding(0, 6, 25, 3),
    Padding = new Padding(0, 3, 0, 0)
};

var button = new Button
{
    BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("../../../Images/cross_200x200.png"),
    BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch,
    Dock = DockStyle.Right,
    Width = 21,
    Height = 21,
    FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat,
};
button.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;

var pan = new Panel
{
    AutoSize = true,
    Padding = new Padding(0, 0, 1, 1),
    BackColor = Color.PowderBlue,
    BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle,
    Tag = keyword
};

button.Click += delegate
{
    _keywords.Remove(pan.Controls.OfType<Label>().First().Text);
    pan.Dispose();
    StatusLabel.Text = $@"Removed {keyword}";
};

pan.Controls.Add(label);
pan.Controls.Add(button);

FlowLayoutPanelMain.Controls.Add(pan);
```

Everytime a "keyword" is added to FlowLayoutPanel control, at first it's a rectangle in top left corner and immediately after that it's fine.

Comment: Do you mean you're using object initializers? I see no anynomous objects in your code. This is an object initializer: `new Button { Left = 40 }`, this is an anonymous object: `new { Left = 40 }`.

Comment: Probably yes, I might be wrong, but do you know why is it happening?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I just thought it might help get you answers if you used the right terminology. It was nitpicking, sorry about that, but I have no idea why it behaves like you show. I initially thought that you were constructing a panel or something, then adding it to the controls collection, and then you set it up by setting properties, but you're doing it correctly as far as I can tell.

Comment: You probably should use SuspendLayout and ResumeLayout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help from a friend of mine, we figured out, that this is happening due to Windows Forms old technology (It's probably not happening in .NET Core's WPF) and it's inability of creating controls at runtime. So, the offered solution for this seems to be just `.Hide()` the control, `.Add()` it to the FlowLayoutPanel and then simply `.Show()` it back, now my eyes will be satisfied.

```
...

pan.Hide();
FlowLayoutPanelMain.Controls.Add(pan);
pan.Show();

...
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try to remove AutoSize property and assign a `new Size()` to the `panel`**

```
AutoSize = false,
```

Worked for me